# Chests won't open in Terraria

Tags: terraria

My personal chests in Terraria stopped opening; only the new chests I place I can open. Does anyone know why this happened and how I can fix it?

Comment: What did you do prior to the chests no longer working? Did you update your game?

Comment: Is your guide alive? You can't spawn the wall of flesh unless your guide is alive.

Comment: By "personal chest" do you mean piggy banks/safes? These are only accessible by one player (like an ender chest in minecraft), so maybe something happened to your player data (if thats even possible)?